# Core data searching error (used NSString)

Tags: core-data, ios7

I have search problem used to core data !

-CASE 1 // It doesn't work

```
-(BOOL)isHeThere:(NSString*)tmpIdm{

    NSString *idm = [tmpIdm uppercaseString];
    NSLog(@"%@",idm);

    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HRData"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"userIdm" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userIdm=%@",idm];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchResults = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request
                                                                     error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",fetchResults);
 // cut follow code
}
```

LOG is

```
2014-04-16 15:07:25.716 MyProject[693:60b] 011204121413310F
2014-04-16 15:07:25.734 MyProject[693:60b] (
)
```

Result is nothing.

but

-Case2 // it is worked

```
-(BOOL)isHeThere:(NSString*)tmpIdm{

    NSString *idm = [tmpIdm uppercaseString];
    NSLog(@"%@",idm);

    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HRData"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"userIdm" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userIdm=%@",@"011204121413310F"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchResults = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request
                                                                     error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",fetchResults);

// cut follow code
]
```

log is

```
2014-04-16 15:05:45.198 MyProject[681:60b] 011204121413310F
2014-04-16 15:05:45.220 MyProject[681:60b] (
    "<HRData: 0x16534d30> (entity: HRData; id: 0x165381e0 <x-coredata://9319373D-1532-42E0-A366-57E5B6E3EBD0/HRData/p47914> ; data: <fault>)"
)
```

Two case used Same code "1234F"

Why I get Different result?

And what's the problem?

+I edited code back (And compile log)

Comment: There's probably some subtle problem in your real code, which we can't see because you doctored it here or typed it back in. You may have fixed your own mistake doing that. The code above wouldn't even compile. One guess is that you accidentally used `tmpCode` in the real code instead of `code`

Comment: Now is real code. but still, don't work  this line "NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userIdm=%@",idm];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];" Used same String "011204121413310F" @Jason Coco

Comment: Hmmm, strange. Try logging the predicate. It should show you: `userIdm == "011204121413310F"` — does it? or does it show you something else?

Comment: !!!! Thank you so much!!!!!! I found my problem!!!! Log "userIdm == "011204121413310F\n"" [\n] <-This is the problem!!!!! @Jason Coco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved like this

```
NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userIdm=%@",idm];
NSLog(@"%@",pred);
```

log

```
2014-04-16 15:23:19.832 SecurityGate[752:60b] userIdm == "011204121413310F
"
```

\n <- Problem